# How do I fix my C# WinForms code to reload a form when called multiple times?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem when calling a new form in C#. In the main form, I have declared the subform AttributesInput frmAttributes = new AttributesInput();
I use the following code to put in a button that invokes a form "AttributesInput".

```
frmAttributes.TopLevel = false;
frmAttributes.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panelMain.Controls.Add(frmAttributes);
frmAttributes.Show();
```

The form is called and loaded successfully. But when I open another form, and then click the button again, the AttributesInput form is still called, showing up but not on the Load() or Shown() event.

I still haven't found a fix yet. I think my code has a problem, I really hope you can help me.

Comment: Your description of the problem is not quite enough for us to figure out what is "wrong". Show us the code to open the other forms, and more of the code from above.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the codes below. it works. I guess you didn't realize that the newly opened form is under the other form.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f3.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f3);
        f3.Show();
    }
```

[Exam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxdTf.png)

add below codes for solution

```
f2.BringToFront();
```

//f2 is a form variable

like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
        f2.BringToFront();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f3.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f3);
        f3.BringToFront();
        f3.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for replying you late. I found a fix after I posted the question,. It's because my code isn't tight enough for the program to work.